# Transform object with nested values and dimensions into one-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, data-structures, flatten

I have an object with following example data model

```js
const partition = {
    values: [
      {
        dimensionValue: 'A',
        numbers: [0, 33],
        partition: {
          values: [
            {
              dimensionValue: '1',
              numbers: [0, 3375],
              partition: {
                values: [
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'a',
                    numbers: [0, 0],
                    partition: null
                  },
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'b',
                    numbers: [0, 8],
                    partition: null
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              dimensionValue: '2',
              numbers: [6028, 0],
              partition: {
                values: [
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'a',
                    numbers: [0, 6028],
                    partition: null
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        dimensionValue: 'B',
        numbers: [0, 31721.57],
        partition: {
          values: [
            {
              dimensionValue: '1',
              numbers: [0, 0],
              partition: {
                values: [
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'a',
                    numbers: [0, 31721.57],
                    partition: null
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I need to transform it into one-dimensional array that will store relation between nested nodes in the `dimension` property, and numbers from the specific node layer in the `values` property. Essentially, output should look like this

```js
[
  {
    "dimensions": ["A"],
    "values": [0, 33]
  },
  {
    "dimensions": ["A", "1"],
    "values": [0, 3375]
  },
  {
    "dimensions": ["A", "1", "a"],
    "values": [0, 0]
  },
  {
    "dimensions": ["A", "1", "b"],
    "values": [0, 8]
  },
  {
    "dimensions": ["A", "2"],
    "values": [6028, 0]
  },
  {
    "dimensions": ["A", "2", "a"],
    "values": [0, 6028]
  },
  {
    "dimensions": ["B"],
    "values": [0, 31721.57]
  },
  {
    "dimensions": ["B", "1"],
    "values": [0, 0]
  },
  {
    "dimensions": ["B", "1", "a"],
    "values": [0, 31721.57]
  }
]
```

My semi-working solution is here.
I'm sure there is some sexy recursive function to use here but I'm struggling to write it.

```js
const partition = {
    values: [
      {
        dimensionValue: 'A',
        numbers: [0, 33],
        partition: {
          values: [
            {
              dimensionValue: '1',
              numbers: [0, 3375],
              partition: {
                values: [
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'a',
                    numbers: [0, 0],
                    partition: null
                  },
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'b',
                    numbers: [0, 8],
                    partition: null
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              dimensionValue: '2',
              numbers: [6028, 0],
              partition: {
                values: [
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'a',
                    numbers: [0, 6028],
                    partition: null
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        dimensionValue: 'B',
        numbers: [0, 31721.57],
        partition: {
          values: [
            {
              dimensionValue: '1',
              numbers: [0, 0],
              partition: {
                values: [
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'a',
                    numbers: [0, 31721.57],
                    partition: null
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }

const extractDimensionValues = (
  partitionValues
) => {
 return (
    partitionValues.flatMap(({ dimensionValue, numbers, partition }) => {
      const mainValues = {
          dimensions: [dimensionValue],
          values: [...numbers],
        }
      const nestedValues = partition.values.flatMap((value) => {
        return ({
          dimensions: [dimensionValue, value.dimensionValue],
          values: [...value.numbers]
        }) 
      })
      
      return !partition.values ? [mainValues] : [mainValues, ...nestedValues]
    })
 )
}

const data = [...extractDimensionValues(partition.values)]
console.log('data :', data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the code so it flattens the `partitionValues` array and `map` over it to extract the relevant dimension `values` and corresponding `numbers`. The extracted data is stored in a new array data which is a one-dimensional array.

**Updated code:**

```js
const partition = {
    values: [
      {
        dimensionValue: 'A',
        numbers: [0, 33],
        partition: {
          values: [
            {
              dimensionValue: '1',
              numbers: [0, 3375],
              partition: {
                values: [
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'a',
                    numbers: [0, 0],
                    partition: null
                  },
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'b',
                    numbers: [0, 8],
                    partition: null
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              dimensionValue: '2',
              numbers: [6028, 0],
              partition: {
                values: [
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'a',
                    numbers: [0, 6028],
                    partition: null
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        dimensionValue: 'B',
        numbers: [0, 31721.57],
        partition: {
          values: [
            {
              dimensionValue: '1',
              numbers: [0, 0],
              partition: {
                values: [
                  {
                    dimensionValue: 'a',
                    numbers: [0, 31721.57],
                    partition: null
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  };

const extractDimensionValues = (partitionValues, currentDimensions = []) => {
  return (
    partitionValues.flatMap(({ dimensionValue, numbers, partition }) => {
      const dimensions = [...currentDimensions, dimensionValue];
      const values = { dimensions, values: [...numbers] };

      if (!partition || !partition.values) {
        return [values];
      }

      return [
        values,
        ...extractDimensionValues(partition.values, dimensions)
      ];
    })
  );
};

const data = [...extractDimensionValues(partition.values)];
console.log('data:', data);
```

Comment: Filip, this is an excellent solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach by using the nested result for mapping with the actual `dimensionValue`.

```js
const
    getFlat = o => o?.values?.flatMap(({ dimensionValue, numbers: values, partition }) => [
        { dimensions: [dimensionValue], values },
        ...getFlat(partition)
            .map(({ dimensions, values }) => ({ dimensions: [dimensionValue, ...dimensions], values }))
    ]) || [],
    partition = { values: [{ dimensionValue: 'A', numbers: [0, 33], partition: { values: [{ dimensionValue: '1', numbers: [0, 3375], partition: { values: [{ dimensionValue: 'a', numbers: [0, 0], partition: null }, { dimensionValue: 'b', numbers: [0, 8], partition: null }] } }, { dimensionValue: '2', numbers: [6028, 0], partition: { values: [{ dimensionValue: 'a', numbers: [0, 6028], partition: null }] } }] } }, { dimensionValue: 'B', numbers: [0, 31721.57], partition: { values: [{ dimensionValue: '1', numbers: [0, 0], partition: { values: [{ dimensionValue: 'a', numbers: [0, 31721.57], partition: null }] } } ] } }] },
    flat = getFlat(partition);

console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another flattening, recursive approach could be based on a single [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task which does recursively create the new flattened partition value from the currently processed item and keeps track of the correct `dimensions` path/array by always passing its recent state as part of an accumulating object which also holds the temporary and the final `result`-array.

```js
function recursivelyCreateAndCollectFlattenedPartitionValue(
  // - the destructured initial value and the accumulated value.
  { result = [], dimensions = [] },
  // - the destructured currently processed array item.
  { dimensionValue, numbers: values, partition = null },
) {
  result
    // - push ...
    .push({
      // ... always the newly created flatened item ...
      dimensions: dimensions.concat(dimensionValue),
      values,
    }, ...(
      // ... and, only if necessary, the `result` array
      //     of the next recursion cycle while "walking the tree". 
      partition?.values.reduce(
        recursivelyCreateAndCollectFlattenedPartitionValue, {
          dimensions: dimensions.concat(dimensionValue),
          result: [],
        },
      ).result ?? []
    ));
  return { result, dimensions: [...dimensions] };
}

const partition = {
  values: [{
    dimensionValue: 'A',
    numbers: [0, 33],
    partition: {
      values: [{
        dimensionValue: '1',
        numbers: [0, 3375],
        partition: {
          values: [{
            dimensionValue: 'a',
            numbers: [0, 0],
            partition: null,
          }, {
            dimensionValue: 'b',
            numbers: [0, 8],
            partition: null,
          }],
        },
      }, {
        dimensionValue: '2',
        numbers: [6028, 0],
        partition: {
          values: [{
            dimensionValue: 'a',
            numbers: [0, 6028],
            partition: null,
          }],
        },
      }],
    },
  }, {
    dimensionValue: 'B',
    numbers: [0, 31721.57],
    partition: {
      values: [{
        dimensionValue: '1',
        numbers: [0, 0],
        partition: {
          values: [{
            dimensionValue: 'a',
            numbers: [0, 31721.57],
            partition: null,
          }],
        },
      }],
    },
  }],
};
const { result: listOfFlattenedPartitionValues } = partition
  .values
  .reduce(recursivelyCreateAndCollectFlattenedPartitionValue, { result: [] });

console.log({ listOfFlattenedPartitionValues });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the solution from Filip Huhta, but with no local variables, and in fact, no statements at all, only expressions:

```js
const flatten = ({values}, path = []) => values .flatMap (
  ({dimensionValue, numbers, partition}) => [
    {dimensions: [...path, dimensionValue], values: numbers},
    ...(partition ? flatten (partition, path .concat (dimensionValue) ): [])                                                      
  ]
)

const partition = {values: [{dimensionValue: "A", numbers: [0, 33], partition: {values: [{dimensionValue: "1", numbers: [0, 3375], partition: {values: [{dimensionValue: "a", numbers: [0, 0], partition: null}, {dimensionValue: "b", numbers: [0, 8], partition: null}]}}, {dimensionValue: "2", numbers: [6028, 0], partition: {values: [{dimensionValue: "a", numbers: [0, 6028], partition: null}]}}]}}, {dimensionValue: "B", numbers: [0, 31721.57], partition: {values: [{dimensionValue: "1", numbers: [0, 0], partition: {values: [{dimensionValue: "a", numbers: [0, 31721.57], partition: null}]}}]}}]}

console .log (flatten (partition))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I find this a very clean way to code.